# Converting a CSV file to an XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml, csv, converters

I am trying to write a java program that will read in a csv file of different bus stop information and convert them to an xml file and save as the new xml file. I had some help with some code from a friend but am unable to understand what the problem is as they forgot to include comments into the code. Any help fixing the code would be greatly appreciated. Code is shown below.

```
public class converter {
protected DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = null;
protected DocumentBuilder domBuilder = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {



    ArrayList<String> busStopInfo = new ArrayList<String>(7);

    File file = new File("stops.csv");
    BufferedReader readFile = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = df.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = db.newDocument();

        Element rootElement = document.createElement("BusStops");

        document.appendChild(rootElement);
        readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int line = 0;

        String information = null;
        while ((information = readFile.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] rowValues = information.split(",");

            if (line == 0) {
                for (String columnInfo : rowValues) {
                    busStopInfo.add(columnInfo);
                }
            } else {
                Element childElement = document.createElement("details");
                rootElement.appendChild(childElement);


                for (int columnInfo = 0; columnInfo < busStopInfo.size(); columnInfo++) {

                    String header = busStopInfo.get(columnInfo);
                    String value = null;

                    if (columnInfo < rowValues.length) {
                        value = rowValues[columnInfo];
                    } else {
                        value = " ";
                    }

                    Element current = document.createElement(header);
                    current.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
                    childElement.appendChild(current);
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            }
            line++;
        }
    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
Writer output = new StringWriter();
tf.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(output));
System.out.println(output.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

}

Below is an Extract of the csv file

AtcoCode,CommonName,LocalityName,ParentLocalityName,Latitude,Longitude
0100BRP90336,The Centre,Bristol City        Centre,Bristol,51.4543379612,-2.5978824115
0170SGA56570,UWE Entrance North,Abbey Wood,,51.50419145,-2.549547265
079073001Z,Bus Station Express Lounge,Middlesbrough,,54.5760020508,-1.2391798779
0800COC31523,Bus Station,Newquay,,50.4130339395,-5.0856695446
0800COC56586,Bus Station,Camborne,,50.2132677521,-5.2974299693

This is the schema for the xml file i am trying to replicate

```
<xs:element name="Busstops">
```

```
    <xs:element name="stops" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AtcoCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="CommonName" type="xs:string" "minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="LocalityName" type="xs:string" "minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="ParentLocalityName" type="xs:string" "minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Longitude" type="xs:string" "minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Latitude" type="xs:string" "minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code? In what way is not doing what you expect?

Comment: it is not outputting and saving the file, i do not have much experience with this language so am very unsure if there is something missing. I run the code and there is no evidence of anything happening.

Comment: You will need to provide a couple of lines from the stops.csv to show the expected input. It would be best if you also had a short example of the expected output.

Comment: Edited to add what you need

Comment: @Granto867 Welcome to SO. You should not destroy the question after its answered. It should stay in the site to help people with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is generating an output converting a .csv that is read to an XML document (displayed on stdout).

Based upon the provided .csv excerpt, the code runs fine, and generates xml on stdout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<BusStops>
<details>
<AtcoCode>0100BRP90336</AtcoCode>
<CommonName>The Centre</CommonName>
<LocalityName>Bristol City Centre</LocalityName>
<ParentLocalityName>Bristol</ParentLocalityName>
<Latitude>51.4543379612</Latitude>
<Longitude>-2.5978824115</Longitude>
</details>
...
</BusStops>
```

If instead of wanting to display it on stdout but write it to a file, you could simply redirect stdout to a file (the easiest approach).

Otherwise, change the `System.out.println(output.toString())` to write to a file. Something like:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.xml", "UTF-8");
writer.println(output.toString());
writer.close();
```

will work.

Comment: i have changed it to the line provided and ran the code with no change in activity. The code doesn't seem to be doing anything. Do i need to create the stops.xml file manually or will the code do that for me ?

Comment: @Granto867, The code does work, and produces the output shown in the answer based upon the sample .csv.  I might suggest putting in a full path to the stops.csv file (e.g., `new File("c:/tmp/stops.csv")`. The program will create a .xml file with the name specified in the PrintWriter. (should probably also use a full path). Versus the schema, the .xml has "details" rather than "stops" as an element, but that is easily fixed in the code.